# Requests are getting timed-out with error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Tags: git, apache, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to push a few repositories from one server to another using git push. It works well for projects that are huge in size (like 90GB) but have a lower number of refs/objects (around 10,000+) inside them. But when I'm trying to push a very small project comparatively (like 2GB), which has a huge number of refs (around 100,000+), it is failing with timeout error as below:
`error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining`

I have checked from the server-side as well and this is the error that I'm encountering:
`(70007)The timeout specified has expired: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed`

I have tried the below things till now with no luck:

- KeepAlive On (In apache httpd.conf)
- Timeout 36000 (In apache httpd.conf)
- KeepAliveTimeout 36000 (In apache httpd.conf)
- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout = 36000 (Ingress Annotation)
- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout = 36000 (Ingress Annotation)
- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout = 36000 (Ingress Annotation)

Any idea why this is being caused and what would be the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening due to the default.conf configurations, somehow taking precedence over the actual httpd.conf file, if anyone wants to know :)